# How safe is it to cat an arbitrary file?

Tags: terminal, cat, special-characters

Sometimes when I `cat` a binary file by mistake, my terminal gets garbled up. Nothing a quick `reset` can't fix, but couldn't an attacker theoretically create a file that, when displayed on a terminal, would execute some arbitrary code? Through an exploit in the terminal emulator or otherwise.

Comment: Sometimes when I do that my shell will say at the end "<garbage> unknown command". That makes me wonder if this is actually possible.

Comment: There were exploits for the terminal emulator, e.g. http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/104657 or http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/6936/discuss so it is not necessary particular safe

Comment: This is why it's better to use something that will balk at binary files (like `more`) or is terminal-aware (`less`) to examine the contents of files.  Not only will it not put your terminal in a weird state, the whole file won't go flying by in one shot.

Comment: `mosh` documentation has some thoughts on that: https://mosh.mit.edu/#techinfo

Comment: See also [Can “cat-ing” a file be a potential security risk?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/can-cat-ing-a-file-be-a-potential-security-risk) and [How to avoid escape sequence attacks in terminals?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/how-to-avoid-escape-sequence-attacks-in-terminals)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, it does not.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1520750/59284.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Whether such output can be exploited depends on the terminal program, and what that terminal does depending on escape codes that are being sent.
I am not aware of terminal programs having such exploitable features, and the only problem now would be if there is an unknown buffer overflow or something like that, that could be exploited.

With some older `hardware` terminals this could be a problem as you programmed e.g. function keys with these kind of escape sequences, by storing a command sequence for that key in the hardware. You would still need a physical key-press to activate that.

But there are always (as Hauke so righfully marked 'braindead') people willing to add such a feature if it solves a problem for them, not understanding the loophole they create. In my experience with open source software is that, because of the many eyes looking at the code, this is less likely to happen as with closed source.  (I remember that in the mail program on Silicon Grahpics' Irix, in the mid ninetees, you could include commands to be executed on the receivers machine, real paths to executables, ....)

Comment: *"you could include commands to be executed on the receivers machine"* You mean something like including in an email VBScript that calls out to the Windows Scripting Host? :)

Comment: No exactly, you could start an executable that was already on the machine, like playing a sound. I don't recall the exact syntax (that was almost 20 years ago) nor whether you could switch that 'feature' off in a setup. We had some fun though with auto-playing videos stored in our network.

Comment: You're not talking about [NeWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeWS) are you? IIRC SGI was one of the last hold-outs.

Comment: @luserdroog No this was the standard GUI based mail program under [Irix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIX)

Comment: Oh, well. I'm a little obsessed with NeWS. :)

Comment: @Anthon I'm not sure if it's still possible, but the possibility of using escape-codes to get a terminal to "repeat" text coming to it from the `write` command - thus executing commands/scripts as the user owning the terminal. It's supposedly the reason why many recommend turning off messages `mesg -n` for users most of the time, and for `root` *always*.  AFAIK, this was actually done - though I don't know if it ever was exploited.  So random text from a `cat`ted executable, *could* perhaps be executed.

Comment: (1) You do realize that [Hauke Laging’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73713/80216#73714) has been deleted, so most people can’t see it, right?  (2) Strictly speaking, Hauke said that the insecure *feature* was braindead, not the implementer.

Answer (score 38):

Most terminal emulators will send back some response, if they receive certain escape sequences (have a look at the [xterm control sequences documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf)). E.g., you can send `\e[0c` to a VT100-like emulator and it will send back the device attributes,
something like `\e[?1;2c` 
(This is probably what Keith observed.) But these answers are not arbitrary strings. Still, having an executable named `2c` somewhere on your system that does something fatal is a bad idea.

Update: The risks are in fact bigger than I thought, due to the possibility to set the title of an xterm window *and to send back the title* using appropriate escape sequences (http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/6940/). In contrast to the example above, the title can be an almost arbitrary string.

Comment: That's already cutting it very close.

Comment: There's an even older feature -- 'answerback message', sent in response to ENQ (C-e) character.  On a real VT100, it is set by the user in the terminal's SETUP menu; maybe there are terminal emulators that allow setting it remotely...

Answer (score 22):

This changes the terminal title in GNOME Terminal 3.6.1, unless overridden by something like [PS1](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/6967a8b1523c8c2828c4c6ee23372a2320bb0d79/.bashrc#L116-L123):

```
printf "\033]2;Script Kiddie was here\007"
```

Now open a new GNOME Terminal window to test the `cat` version:

```
printf "\033]2;Script Kiddie was here\007" > test.bin
cat test.bin
```

Yep, this also sets the terminal title.

There used to be a security issue with [an escape code resulting in the title being printed to the command line](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=613110), so you could effectively create a file, which when `cat`ed would print (I'm not sure if you could put a newline in there) arbitrary commands. Ouch!

Answer (score 15):

While using `cat` might not result in code execution, escape codes will be processed so you could easily be misled into thinking the script is harmless when in fact it is malicious.

Here is an example command you can run which will create a "malicious" shell script:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\necho "...doing something bad here..."\nexit\n\033[A\033[Aecho "Hello dear reader, I am just a harmless script, safe to run me!"' > demo.sh
chmod a+x demo.sh
```

When you inspect the file, it seems harmless enough:

```
$ cat demo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello dear reader, I am just a harmless script, safe to run me!"
```

But should you actually run it...

```
$ ./demo.sh 
...doing something bad here...
```

The script works by including raw escape codes to move the cursor up a couple of lines, so the rest of the script is written over the top of the malicious code, hiding it.

Nearly any other program will reveal the script for what it is.  Only programs that don't process the file content (like `cat`, `more` and `less -r`) will produce the misleading output.

Note that `tail` and `head` also produce the same misleading output. Using  "less +F" is therefore safer than "tail -f".

Comment: This is quite problematic... You can see what's actually going on by running `echo $(cat demo.sh)`, `cat demo.sh | grep . --color=yes` (Note: the `--color=yes` is what's showing the "malicious" code here) or the build-in `cat -v demo.sh`.

Comment: True or false, it’s an answer for a different question: how trustworthy is `cat` in displaying the file’s *content*.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: It's not really an answer for a different question. This answer warns that cat will show escape codes, and provides a simple example with only one type of escape code, but there are many others. When combined with certain terminals, these can remap keys, overwrite files and in theory, [even execute commands](https://www.proteansec.com/linux/blast-past-executing-code-terminal-emulators-via-escape-sequences/). So once you realise the danger of displaying escape codes, you will understand that it can sometimes be unsafe to `cat` an arbitrary file, as the question asked!

Answer (score 8):

I have definitely experienced `xterm` inserting arbitrary characters into itself as if I had typed them. And on occasion this has apparently included newline character, so that I got `ngwerm:0riu: command not found` as a response. I see no reason why someone could not craft a file that would send specific, harmful commands. So yes, at least some terminals are susceptible to attacks with arbitrary impact.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a terminal emulator basically simply prints out the characters sent to it.

Anything besides simply printing a character on the current position, like setting a new position, changing color, changing title, etc., is done by escape sequences.

The set of supported escape sequences usually consists of well defined standards like [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which does not define a way to start other processes. Although it would be possible to implement such a sequence, I am not aware of any terminal emulator intentionally allowing such things.

In theory a bug like a buffer overflow might be used to trigger arbitrary functionality. But this would be possible in pretty much any other binary, too.

Answer (score 1):

In general there is usually no risk to catting an arbitrary file. My usual method for analyzing a file is to do the following:

```
$ file <mystery file>
$ strings <mystery file> | less
```

The above allows me to determine a file's type through the `file` command and the `strings` command allows me to dump any identifiable strings from would-be binary files that I"m not sure about their lineage.

#### example

*file output*

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

*strings output*

```
$ strings /bin/ls|less
...
across
vertical
single-column
force
never
auto
if-tty
slash
%b %e  %Y
%b %e %H:%M
long-iso
main
posix-
sort_files
?pcdb-lswd
dev_ino_pop
Try `%s --help' for more information.
Usage: %s [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort.
Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --all                  do not ignore entries starting with .
  -A, --almost-all           do not list implied . and ..
...
```

Comment: running strings on an unknown file can also have problematic consequences. http://lcamtuf.blogspot.fi/2014/10/psa-dont-run-strings-on-untrusted-files.html

Comment: @IncnisMrsi - read the first sentence!!!!

Comment: OK, retracting my previous statement, The answer is short, using confusing terminology, unfounded, and evidently incomplete. Note that in security, “arbitrary” ≠ random as distributed in your favourite OS.