# Literally printing with zcat

Tags: bash, command-line, manjaro, zip, rxvt

I'm a beginner in Linux world. Today I encountered something really weird. I used `zcat` command on a .zip file (this one, it's a manual for a motherboard: https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7A70v1.0.zip). It printed output to the terminal as expected. What surprised me the most is the fact that afterwards my printer started printing binary data as text. It printed about half a page and then stopped. Can anyone tell me what happened? How is it possible? I'm using Manjaro, bash and urxvt.

Command that I used:
`zcat E7A70v1.0.zip`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-safe-is-it-to-cat-an-arbitrary-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output contains (among other things) a valid escape sequence telling urxvt to print the current screen: <kbd>*ESC*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd><kbd>**`i`**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The zip archive contains a pdf file (`E7A70v1.0.pdf`), not a plain text file. Pdf files may (and probably do) contain binary data mixed with text.

You want to extract the pdf file with `unzip E7A70v1.0.zip`, and then use a pdf viewer to read the file you have extracted. You have your choice of viewers, but `evince` is a good one, and comes with most Linux distributions.