# Carriage return with echo command

Tags: shell, echo, newlines

I was practicing echo command with option `\r` (carriage return) as below.

```
echo -e "This is \r my college"
```

output:

```
 my college
```

but when I add one more word before `\r` as below

```
echo -e "This is the \r my college"
```

Then it gives me output like:

```
 my college the
```

Another example

```
echo -e "This is \r valid data"
 valid data

echo -e "This is not a \r valid data"
 valid data a
```

So, I wanted to know that what is the actual purpose of carriage return here?

Comment: This is not reproducible. The second command results in the output `␣my college`, just like the first one.

Comment: `echo -e` is notoriously unportable. You shoud probably use `printf` instead.

Comment: Related : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355559/bash-and-carriage-return-behavior

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `\r` is just that, a "carriage return" - nothing else. This means what is after the `\r` will overwrite the beginning of what has already been printed.

For example:

```
echo -e "1234\r56"
```

Will display:

```
5634
```

`echo` has printed `1234` then gone back to the begining of the line and printed `56` over the top of `12`.

For a new line, try `\n` instead. No need for spaces too. For example:

```
echo -e "This is\nmy college"
```

Which will output:

```
This is
my college
```

The carriage return is useful for things like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
while [ $i -lt 3 ]
do
    echo -ne "\r"`date` #you should remove new line too
    sleep 1
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
exit
```

Which will display `date` over the top of itself instead of creating a new line after each loop.

Comment: carriage return is also used in the sysvinit provided functions. For example the function `echo_success` from `/etc/init.d/functions`.

Answer (score 2):

Tigger has a good answer about what the `\r` does. One other trick for the Bourne shell (which works in different ways in other shells) is to clear the end of the line like so:

```
#/bin/sh -e
echo "this is a first line...\r\c"
...other code...
echo "another line\033[K\r\c"
```

Without the `\033[K` (kill the end of the line), you would get:

```
another lineirst line...
```

With the `\033[K` the output from the cursor position to the end of the line is cleared so the result of the above is:

```
another line
```

This is practical for scripts that take a long time and you want to let the user know where you're at (i.e. maybe a path your script is working on and the next path is shorter).

**Note:** As a side note, I'd like to specify that the `\n` is what sends your cursor to the next line. In the old MS-DOS console, it just goes one line down, same column. This is why under MS-Windows you are still expected to write both characters (`\r\n`). Although in most cases people just write `\n` and things work as expected because the `FILE` has a "text mode" which inserts a `\r` before each `\n` (and also mangles binary files every so often...).